# How to get a bounding box for a HTMLAgilityPack DOM element in C#?

Tags: c#, dom, rendering, html-agility-pack

My application uses [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com) to download HTML documents and analyze their DOM structure with a lot of XPath queries. Disclaimer: XPath support is extremely important for my purposes, I cannot switch to CSS selectors, for example. This is the main (and, probably, the only) reason why I use HtmlAgilityPack.

I have an `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode`, chosen from a HTML document with some XPath query. Now I need to implement one additional method: *What would be the bounding box coordinates of this element, if it was rendered by some engine?* I don't even care which particular engine is used, let it be WebKit, MSIE, Gecko/Firefox etc. I just need a way to:

1. Render a document in memory on an arbitrarily sized canvas (say, 1900*1200 pixels).
2. Setup a one-to-one correspondence between a renderer's DOM tree and the `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument` that I already have.
3. Ask a renderer for a bounding box of a particular DOM element (`HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode`) on this canvas.

I already spent half a day looking into various HTML rendering engines for .NET but still haven't found a way to do this. Maybe someone has already solved a similar problem? Thank you for any help.

Comment: [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/) looks to be a right tool for this job.

Comment: @Noseratio I tried Awesomium. I did not find a way to do #3 in it.

Comment: #3 is not specific to Awesomium. If the desired HTML element doesn't  have an `id` attribute, generate a unique ID and assign it to the element with HTML Agility Pack. If there's an `id`, use it (make sure it's unique). Load the document into the HTML engine, then just do `document.getElementById(id).getBoundingClientRect()`. Both Awesomium and WebBrowser Control provide bindings to access the DOM.

Comment: Ultimately, a whole "browsing context" needs to be setup (javascripts, network, referrer, cookies, web services, etc...) for an html element to be rendered properly. Or if the pages are so simple that you can just load them in any browser, what's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add custom attribute. Then find it in WebBrowser control.
Something like [this](http://www.kurilo.su/stackoverflow/18094321_TestApplication.zip).

Comment: Hmm. Is there a way to search for marked elements in WebBrowser more efficiently? Enumerating the entire tree all the time looks pricey.

Comment: You can previously find all getElementsByTagName.

Comment: @Skiminok, is it a single `HtmlNode` or many for one document? The DOM tree traversal would be a very little price comparable to actual loading, parsing and rendering of the document by WebBrowser (or any other HTML engine in that sense).

Comment: @Noseratio multiple for one document, many times. I suppose I can just build a hashtable of them after a single traversal (and possibly some other efficient data structures to go the other way around and retrieve nodes by coordinate, if WebBrowser doesn't provide a way to do it already).

Comment: @Dmitry, it's a decent piece of code which appears to get the job done, +1 from me :)

Comment: @Skiminok, you may want to have a look at [IDisplayServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752659(v=vs.85).aspx), it may help with the coordinates mapping if you stick with `WebBrowser`.

Comment: @DmitryKurilo For some reason, this code with only slight modifications never works for me. Here is my version: http://pastebin.com/hzg07Gna The `DocumentCompleted` event is never called (even though I'm creating a `WebBrowser` in a STA thread with a message pump).

Comment: @DmitryKurilo Interesting, thanks. Apparently, <base href="..."> tag is not important here, but the "present attribute" filter is. I will now accept this answer, thank you again.

Comment: @Skiminok, WebBrowser control won't be able to recieve styles, images and scripts without the base tag. As far as I think.